# Dapper ORM - Insert object with existing Id

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm getting data from an API that returns this object:

```js
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Sucesso",
  "count": 2,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 18476,
      "date": "2020-12-25",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "phone": "11111111111",
      "text": "Teste de homologação DJN em produção.",
      "process": "00100522320208220501",
      "type": "D"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to insert it into the Database I get the field "id" equals to NULL.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnectionString("cnn")))
{
    connection.Open();
    var identity = connection.Insert(my_object);
}
```

The "connection.Insert()" method used is from [Dapper Contrib Extensions](https://dapper-tutorial.net/insert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you just need to use this annotation: `[ExplicitKey]` before the `Id` field.

[Reference](https://dapper-tutorial.net/data-annotation-explicitkey)

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//...

[Table("your_table")]
public class Publicacao
{
        [ExplicitKey]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Process { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
}
```